# Show that if $ 0 < c2 < c1 < 1$, there may be no step lengths that satisfy the Wolfe conditions.

Tags: proof-explanation, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

$f(x + αp) ≤ f(x) + c_1α∇f^Tp$, (3.6a)

$∇f(x + αp)^Tp ≥ c_2∇fk^Tp$, (3.6b)

Why is it that when $0 < c2 < c1 < 1$, there is no step lengths that satisfy the Wolfe conditions.

I thought about doing this graphically but I am not sure how to do that.